# Can I run a 775 DC motor with DC solid state relay?

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, 12v, solid-state-relay

I want to run a 775 DC motor with 12V DC power battery.DC motor link:https://www.nbleisonmotor.com/RS-775-Dc-Micro-Motor-pd6675924.html
I didn’t find any suitable controller for this. The controller should be output controlled of 12V DC with 5V DC input. Finally I thought to use DC solid state relay. Can DC solid state relay run the DC motor? Can you please help here, how can I run, or can you please suggest a small size 775 motor controller?
The following link included the DC SSR.
[https://www.amazon.com/SSR-25DD-Solid-Control-Output-5-60VDC/dp/B086PWF485](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086PWF485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, per the data given in your question and shown with 775 DC motor. The azon link "https://www.amazon.com/775-Motor-12V-6000-12000-Electronic/dp/B08662QSZL" shows: "Brand SP, Speed 12000 RPM, Voltage 12 Volts
Brand   SP
Speed   12000 RPM
Voltage 12 Volts
Horsepower  12000 Watts ( That is just over 16 HP )
That would require requires about 100 Amps at 12V.
I would suggest you check the data posted and add links to the devices showing the correct technical information.

Comment: I added the motor link, can you please suggest there have any mosfet to control this motor  so that i can drive with 555 timer by generating PWM. Actually first time i used IRF3205 smd version, after running 30 second the IRP3205 mosfet got burned. Can you please suggest how can i control with small size controller or other. Thanks

Comment: That motor has a stall current of 110A, but the maximum operating current is less than 55A. A 100A SSR should be sufficient.

Comment: That MOSFET should work however it must be driven properly with proper heatsinking.  Post a schematic of your circuit. You need a minimum of at least 6Vgs to enhance enough to hold the current you are talking about. 10V would be much better. You can pick another MOSFET that has a lower Vgs, preferable a avalanche rated device.

Answer (score 1):

No, just a solid state relay is probably not sufficient. Even though the motor specifications in the link provided by another answer are very badly presented, they indicate that it is likely that the motor requires an electronic controller to limit the motor's starting current. If you are buying the motor from a seller that provides proper specifications, determine what to expect for starting current and whether or not the starting current will damage the motor or the power source.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i thought so, when the motor will be turned on with solid state relay,  motor will draw very high current, since i am using 12V Battery so it charge will go down quickly by many time on and off. Can you please suggest which mosfet can i use so that i can drive with 555 timer by generating PWM. Actually first time i used IRF3205 smd version, after running 30 second the IRP3205 mosfet got burned.  Can you please suggest how can i control with small size controller or other. Thanks

Comment: An electronic controller of a DC motor requires more than a timer and a mosfet. I can't help with that and I think it is more than can be done in this question and answer format.